# Get row with the lowest id from multiple rows?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains several columns, one of them is entity_id (PK) and parent_id. The parent_id is a FK and it can come up several times with a different entity_id. Now, is there a way to say "select that row of the table where the entity_id is lowest for a given parent_id"?

Something like this:

```
select * from my_table where entity_id = min(entity_id) and parent_id = 123;
```

Hope you know what I mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a simple subquery;

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE entity_id = (SELECT MIN(entity_id) FROM my_table WHERE parent_id = 123);
```

...or, less obviously a `LEFT JOIN` to find all rows where there exists no row with the same parent_id and a smaller entity_id;

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM my_table a
LEFT JOIN my_table b ON a.parent_id = b.parent_id AND a.entity_id > b.entity_id
WHERE b.entity_id IS NULL AND a.parent_id = 123;
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to show both](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d404/4).

The latter can also be used to find the smallest entity_id for all parent_id's at once by just leaving out the condition on parent_id being 123.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   * 
from my_table 
where entity_id = (SELECT min(entity_id) FROM my_table WHERE parent_id = 123);
```